# Struts 2 : How many times an Interceptor would be called if its configured for one Action class

Tags: struts2

I have a question with respect to interceptors in Struts2

> Struts2 provides very powerful mechanism of controlling a request using Interceptors. Interceptors are responsible for most of the request processing. They are invoked by the controller before and after invoking action, thus they sits between the controller and action. Interceptors performs tasks such as Logging, Validation, File Upload, Double-submit guard etc.

I have taken this above lines from:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/12/struts2-interceptors-tutorial-with-example.html

> In this example you will see how the interceptors are invoked both before and after the execution of the action and how the results are rendered back to the user.

I have taken this above lines from

http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-interceptors-example-1.html

I have written a basic interceptor and plugged it to my Action class:

```
public class InterceptorAction implements Interceptor {
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("Action class has been called : ");
       return success;
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="login" class="com.DBAction">
   <interceptor-ref name="mine"></interceptor-ref>
   <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
   <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

As per the above statements from their sites , i assumed that this line Action class has been called would be two times on the console (That is before the Action and after the Action class ) , but it has been printed only once?

PLease let me know , if my understanding is wrong , or the authors were wrong in that site ??

Comment: The short version of Quaternion's answer: interceptors aren't "invoked twice", interceptors wrap an action invocation just like a servlet filter "surrounds" a servlet request. The only "gotcha" is that the result has been rendered by the time control returns to the interceptor; if you want to do something before the result is rendered, you must implement a `PreResultListener`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not taking the time to read the page lets clear a few things up...

You are missing an important step in your interceptor.

Struts2, uses an object called **ActionInvocation** to manage calling the interceptors.

Lets give ActionInvocation a name (invocation) and show how the framework starts the ball rolling:

```
ActionInvocation invocation;
invocation.invoke(); //this is what the framework does... this method then calls the first interceptor in the chain.
```

Now we know interceptors can do pre-processing and post-processing... but the interface only defines one method to do the work of the interceptor (init and delete are just life cycle)! If the interface defined a doBefore and doAfter it would be easy so there must be some magic, happening...

As it turns out you are responsible for giving control back to action invocation at some point in your interceptor.  This is a requirement. If you don't give control back to the ActionInvocation you will break the chain.

So when creating an interceptor you do the following steps

1. Create a class which implements com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor
2. [optional] do pre-processing work
3. call ActionInvocations invoke method to carry on processing down the stack and capture the return value.
4. [optional] do post processing as the above call unwinds.
5. return the string from step 3 (the result string) unless you have reason to do otherwise.

And here is a complete but pretty useless example:

```
package com.quaternion.interceptors;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        //nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Something to do before the action!");
        String resultString = invocation.invoke();
        System.out.println("Something to do after the action!");
        return resultString;
        //if you are not doing post processing it is easiest to write
        //return invocation.invoke();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ya , Thanks i understood when i added this line and thanks once again .if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
    {
   System.out.println("After the Action");
    }